# Get an image that's the difference between two images (Java Graphics2D)

Tags: java, border, bufferedimage, cut

Here's what I'm trying to do:
Get an image that's the difference between two images.

Context:
I have 2 images (identical) but one is bigger than the other.
I superimpose the smaller one in the center of the bigger one.

I would like to retrieve an image that is the difference between the 2 images.

Expected outcome:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4mav.png]

What code would you propose to do that in an efficient way?

Edit :
I didn't specify the way.
I work in a Graphics2D context with BufferedImage

Comment: Your description do not match title at all. When you say borders of an image what comes to mind is rectangular border of ImageBox or something.  And please be more specific, are you are using built in vector graphics in JavaFx or just bitmap images (png/jpg)? and what java UI framework (swing, JavaFX) ??

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post. I didn't specify the way.
I work in a Graphics2D graphic context with BufferedImage

Comment: You should be able to use an `AlphaComposite`. See: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mer0918/ for more information and a complete working example.

Answer (score 0):

Thank a lot Camickr !

It was very simple so far.
Here is the result :

...
BufferedImage finalCut = extractEdge(source, dest);
...
g2d.drawImage(buff, 100, 100, null);
...

```
public static BufferedImage extractEdge(BufferedImage imgBottom, BufferedImage imgTop)
{
    BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(imgBottom.getWidth(), imgBottom.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2dBuff = buffer.createGraphics();

    g2dBuff.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.XOR));
    g2dBuff.drawImage(imgBottom, 0, 0, null);
    g2dBuff.drawImage(imgTop, (int) getCenter(0, imgBottom.getWidth(), imgTop.getWidth(), true), (int) getCenter(0, imgBottom.getHeight(), imgTop.getHeight(), true), null);
    
    return buffer;
}

public static float getCenter(float startZone, float zoneLenght, float elementLenght, boolean round)
{
    float s = startZone + (zoneLenght - elementLenght) / 2f;
    return (round) ? Math.round(s) : s;
}
```

[Final cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCIgq.jpg)